# Ruby and Watir; randomly select option from select_list that does NOT have "disabled" in the attribute

Tags: arrays, ruby, watir-webdriver

Running Watir tests where I am looking to select a *random* value from a select_list element.  By default, one of the options has the attribute `disabled value="true"`

Currently I am putting all the options into an array like such:

```
@browser.select_list(:class, 'preset-select').options.to_a.sample.click
```

Normally this works in selecting a single option, but I occasionally run into an issue where it tries to click on the disabled object instead.

How would I validate this to ensure the object returned is not a disabled one?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the list of options to those that are enabled:

```
enabled_options = @browser.select_list(:class, 'preset-select').options.select(&:enabled?)
enabled_options.sample.click
```

Comment: Hmm.... I am getting an error saying `enabled?` is an undefined method for `Watir::Option`.  I _am_ running an older version of watir-webdriver though, could that be the hiccup?

Comment: What version are you using? I don't remember when the `#enabled?` method was added.

Comment: I have `v0.6.11`.

Comment: `#enabled?` was added in v0.9.0. For v0.6.11, try `@browser.select_list(:class, 'preset-select').options.select { |o| !o.disabled?}`